# Using BeautifulSoup to extract <span> tags to content page numbers

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Hello everyone I'm starting with python + beautufulsoup4 + requests and need to remove the tags span without any id or class cut to extract the number of pages I need to go or scrap of this fragment of code page I just need to remove the

```html
<div class="pagination">
    <select id="CurrentPage" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field CurrentPage must be a number." data-val-required="The CurrentPage field is required." name="CurrentPage">
    <option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    </select>
    <span>of 28</span>
    <a class="btn next" href="/listings/trucks/for-sale/list/category/27/trucks/manufacturer/international/model-group/9400?page=2">Next »</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
span_tag = soup.find(name='span',text=re.compile(r'of \d+'))
page_num = span_tag.text.rstrip('of ')
```

Comment: Thanks to help me i prec